# D3 line chart connect with MySQL database in PHP

Tags: php, json, d3.js

I create database and try to connect with D3 chart but it is not working.please help me
I try it with [link](http://www.d3noob.org/2013/02/using-mysql-database-as-source-of-data.html)

```
d3.json("data.php", function(error, data) {
  data.forEach(function(d) {
    d.value1 = +d.value1;
    d.value2 = +d.value2;
});
```

Comment: What errors if any are you getting? What exactly does data.php return when you get it?

Comment: I use json_encode in data.php but it not work.then i pass value from with data.json file .it is success.but my task is not complete.

Comment: We really need to see the actual JSON In order to offer opinions.